# Can't serve static html files with ASP.NET Core Web Application - what am I missing?

Tags: asp.net

I am getting 404 response when trying to view a static html file. I know I am missing something but I have not been able to find the answer. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. In visual studio 2015 with update 3 (with [.Net Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015) installed).  File>New>Project>ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Framework)   button  Web API (No Authentication)   button
2. In project.json add the following line in the dependencies:

   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.1",  (save)
3. I do not think it is required but I ran (in admin mode)  dotnet restore (root dir)
4. In Startup.cs I added the following lines in the Configure function:

   app.UseStaticFiles();
   app.UseDefaultFiles();
5. Rebuild and run F5  The Web API page comes up just fine:

   http://localhost:50666/api/values
6. I get 404 error with

   http://localhost:50666/Project_Readme.html

Note that as of today (12/16/16) the default template creates the Project_Readme.html file in the root. And Program.cs already has int the main...

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();
```

I tried different orderings of the app.Use***.
I tried renaming Project_Readme.html to index.html.

What step am I missing?

Comment: Looks like your web root folder is configured as usual, to `wwwroot` and this is from where static files are served by default. If you need static files server from other locations (like the root folder of your app, you have to add it in an explicit way). More on that here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files. Let me know if this is a correct answer, as I am merely guessing your actual issue is just forgeting about the default static content folder location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41093539/240564

Answer (score 3):

By default static files should be in wwwroot folder, but Project_Readme.html is not there, that's why you can't see it. But you can configure the static files middleware.

Please see details in my [other answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41093539/240564).

And [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files).

Comment: Yes, that was it. Embarrassing ... Thanks for the quick replies.