# ASP MVC allow static html files

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, static-files

I have a simple ASP MVC project. 
Under this site I need to show plain .html files, without treating routes as *controller/action*.

I have folder *documentation* with file *index.html* in it.
I need to have this accessible under *www.mydomain.com/documentation*, it returns 403.
Currently it works only under *www.mydomain.com/documentation/index.html*

I have added

```
routes.Ignore("developers/");
```

into `RouteConfig.cs`

and in `Startup.cs` for OwinAppBuilder

```
        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

What should I do to have it accessible under *www.mydomain.com/documentation/index.html* ?

Comment: are you able to serve other static files, like .js and .png? Also what version of IIS are you running?

Comment: nor Core? For Core see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41093539/240564

Comment: well I can actually show the file, the problem is that I need to explicitly write "index.html" into URL... when I disable all MVC, and have site running, everything works

Answer (score 1):

In your route config add

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "staticFileRoute",
    url: "Public/{*file}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "HandleStatic" }
);
```

In you web.config under `<system.webServer>/<handlers>` add

```
<add name="MyCustomUrlHandler2" path="Public/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Taken from [this](https://prerakkaushik.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/routing-request-for-static-files-with-or-without-extension-in-asp-net-mvc/) site if you want to read more about it.

Edit: note that the url in the `MapRoute` has the directory `Public` in the url, as well as in the `path` for the web.config line. If your html file is not in a directory named `Public` you will need to change that part to match your directory structure.

Comment: well this handles routes like domain.com/documentation/index.html.. but I need the opposite, I need to transform urls like domain.com/documentation  into domain.com/documentation/index.html, to show the html file

Comment: Give this a look: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4552992/6442320](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4552992/6442320)